# Why Web Api (.Net Core) always return JSON ignored the value in ContentType?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 web APIs and they have the exactly same code and same references.

- The first one (called Project A) runs under .net 4.6 and is the old web api project
- The second one (called Project B) runs under .net 4.6 too but is the new .Net core web api project.

I used the same reference as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
```

And here is the code that they both use.

```
public HttpResponseMessage TestReport()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    PdfDocument document = HelloWorld();

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        document.Save(memoryStream, false);


        byte[] buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        var contentLength = buffer.Length;
        response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        // Byte Array Test
        //response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        //response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        //response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
        //response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "anything.pdf";
        //response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");


        //var test = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        // Stream Content Test
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(buffer));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
        if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("attachment; filename=" + "helloWorld" + ".pdf", out contentDisposition)) {
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
        }

        return response;
    };
}

public PdfDocument HelloWorld()
{
    // Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

    // Create an empty page
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    //XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

    // Create a font
    XFont font = new XFont("Times New Roman", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

    // Draw the text
    gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
        new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
        XStringFormats.Center);

    // Save the document...
    const string filename = "HelloWorld_tempfile.pdf";
    //document.Save(filename);
    return document;


}
```

When i call them (either from another controller or from a browser), they produce 2 different results

- The project A returns Pdf files with correct response header is application/pdf
- The project B always returns Json (application/json) format doesn't matter what i set in the response header. I have tried xml, text, stream, bytearrays. Nothing works.

My questions are:

- what the heck is going on? is Microsoft @#%^& it again?
- Is anything i can do for the project B to return correct response (as I defined)

P/S: This is my web.config files

Project B: Default from template (i cannot paste it here, not sure why)

Project A: Default from template (i cannot paste it here, not sure why)

Comment: You have to send the `accept` header with the correct value.

Comment: Please share the WebApiConfig.cs from the working api project

Comment: Hi guys, this is my Web.config `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>`

Comment: Sorry for the mess, i cannot format the xml things on stackoverflow. Basically, i used the default web.config. No modification.

Comment: @Dr.Fre would you mind clarify on your comment? I am not quite sure how to do that? but why do i need to do that in the .netcore (target .net 4.6) project

Comment: @romeo.Do take a look [here](http://dotnetthoughts.net/content-negotiation-in-aspnet-core/)

Comment: @Dr.Fre what about pdf and other type such as audio and image? I cannot find any of those formatters on nuget? Am i missing something?

Comment: @romeo.Do sorry was a bit misleading. There seems to be no built in formater for pdfs. You could build one or just force the return type to be a pdf. Maybe that makes more sense anyway as maybe a pdf cannot be representet as json. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36043779/6583901) is a good example.

Comment: @Dr.Fre The link you gave doesn't work. That instruction only applicable to the pure asp.net core project using standard platform 1.x.

Comment: @Dr.Fre thanks for your suggestion. I had tried the suggestion on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042614/how-to-return-a-pdf-from-a-web-api-application/36043779#36043779). Unfortunately, none of those works. The api always return json format, doesn't matter what i do. And there is no way i can get the pdf file data from that json format @_@!!

Answer (score 2):

asp.net-core does not support `HttpResponseMessage` by default, which was from previous version of Web API. Core is seeing that `HttpResponseMessage` in the action result as a model and is serializing it to JSON.

Refactor Project B code...

```
public IActionResult TestReport() {        
    var document = HelloWorld();
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        document.Save(memoryStream, false);
        var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        contentDisposition.SetHttpFileName("helloWorld.pdf");
        Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = contentDisposition.ToString();
        return File(buffer, "application/pdf");
    }            
}
```