# PDF Document to WebAPI for download

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js, pdfsharp

I have a page that allows a user to click a button, and it makes a WebAPI call to my .Net backend controller which generates a PDFSharp document object. I need to return that (binary?) object to the Knockout/Javascript caller on the UI, and present a Save As dialog... or else just start downloading it automatically.

This is my attempt, but it's not right.

```
 [System.Web.Http.Route("GeneratePdf"), System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage GeneratePdf(PlateTemplateExtendedDto data)
        {

            var doc = GeneratePdf(new PlateService().CreateTemplate(true), "my.pdf");

            HttpResponseMessage result = null;

            var pdfContent = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(pdfContent);

            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(pdfContent, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "SampleImg"


            //pdfContent.Position = 0;

            var res = new HttpResponseMessage();
            res.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfContent.ToArray());

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = data.Description;
            res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return res;
        }
```

Firstly, the line:

```
new StreamContent(new FileStream(pdfContent, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
```

is invalid. 'pdfContent' should be a string, I think.

Secondly, I'm not sure how to handle a 'HttpResponseMessage' on the front end. How do I turn that into a Download?

Comment: so you can't save the pdf somewhere and return the path to the client so it could be a link? (that is usually how I do pdfs using web api / knockout)

Comment: Here is one of my previous answers for returning pds from asp.net-web-api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042614/how-to-return-a-pdf-from-a-web-api-application/36043779#36043779

Comment: @BryanDellinger - That's certainly an option, but the PDF validity is pretty short for the process I'm doing, so then I'd need something that deletes the file or cleans out the folder. Also, I'm on shared hosting, so not sure i have access to save files. At the moment, I render an image and display it without saving to disk - I'm hoping I can do the same with a pdf.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi - That nearly works. I am just not getting Headers back. It just downloads a file. If I rename it after downloading to file.pdf, the file opens.... I'm just unable to get the headers. header = headers() fails saying headers() is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web api may be something like this..

```
        [System.Web.Http.Route("GeneratePdf"), System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GeneratePdf(PlateTemplateExtendedDto data)
        {
            var doc = GeneratePdf(new PlateService().CreateTemplate(true), "my.pdf");
            var pdfContent = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(pdfContent);
            var content =  new StreamContent(pdfContent);
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = data.Description;
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            content.Headers.ContentLength = pdfContent.GetBuffer().Length;
            return Ok(content);
        }
```

you only set api url  with PlateTemplateExtendedDto parameters to window.location  on client side