# How do you read a pdf in C# and return the file to the user?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, download

I've got a C#, Kendo MVC, Razor project.  The user clicks on a row in a Kendo grid, that fires an on change event, that event makes an api call to the controller, which reads in a pdf file, and returns it to the user to download.  I've done this with csv files and it's worked fine, but with pdfs I get an error.  Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work with pdfs?

Javascript in View

```
window.location = "/api/WoApi/GetPDF/1?pdf=" + JSON.stringify(ID);
```

C# in Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public System.Net.WebResponse GetPDF(string pdf)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Projects\\Attachments\\Invoice_2424.pdf");
    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    return response;
}
```

Error message

```
> <Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Net.FileWebResponse' with data contract name 'FileWebResponse:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass7.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__6() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

** UPDATE #1 **

I got the following code to return a file, but I still get the same error message:

```
string file = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Projects\\Attachments\\Invoice_2424.pdf";
var test = new System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult(file, "application/pdf");
return test;
```

Error message:

```
Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.GetDataContract(DataContract declaredTypeContract, Type declaredType, Type objectType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass7.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__6() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to return just a file specifying the url with the proper mimetype.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPDF(string pdf)
{
    string file = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Projects\\Attachments\\Invoice_2424.pdf";

    return File(file, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What type is "File" in your example?  I tried System.IO.File(file, "application/pdf"); but it says "File cannot be used like a method".

Comment: It is a `FilePathResult` and should come in from `using System.Web.Mvc` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Can't get this to work.  If I use just File(file, "application/pdf") I get the "cannot be used like a method".  If I use System.Web.Mvc.File(file, "application/pdf") I get File does not exist in the namespace.  If I use System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult(file, "application/pdf") I get the "cannot be used like a method" error (FilePathResult comes from the link you sent).  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I updated the answer. The method need to return an ActionResult for this to work.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work the way you wrote it, but if create a new FilePathResult instance it will return a file.  I've updated my original answer so you can see the code.  However, I still get an error message.  Maybe because it's a pdf?  Any suggestions?

Comment: You might look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36043779/567446 Most of my experience on this is in MVC not the API. You might try setting the header type.

Answer (score -1):

CSV file may be worked because it is text based format, but pdf is not.

Looks like you are using web API,

Try this way,

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Generate()
{

     var stream = new FileStream("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Projects\\Attachments\\Invoice_2424.pdf", FileMode.Open);

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "fileName.pdf"
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What libraries are Response and File from?  I get an error with Response saying it "does not exist in the current context" and with File "System.IO.File...cannot be used like a method".  See my conversation with Locke125 too.  Sounds like this will work if I can just get the right libraries.

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net MVC ?

Comment: 'Response'  and `File(filedata, contentType)` are coming from  is coming from System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: I've updated my question with my updated code trying this.  Unfortunately, I still get the same error.  I'm guessing it's because it's a pdf file.  Any idea how to get the pdf file to download once it gets back to the client side?

Comment: Looks like you are using web API ? Please see my update code above