# What is the best way to pass a set of parameters to a website?

Tags: asp.net, api, web-services, parameters

I need to pass several parameters to a website (MVC web app built in VS2017) that in turn will be constructing a PDF that is returned to the viewer.

Something like this:
http://mywebsite.com?strAssetID=E2BEB600&strUserID=59&strGIU=1

I've been told that this is only possible with an API (i.e. REST API)

So does the web app need to be a REST API?
i.e. it can't be a simple hello world website?

Is there a better way to pass the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an MVC Web App then it should be relatively easy to add an Endpoint to it (e.g. `/api/pdf/get?<your params>`) that does this. MVC has great support for API responses, see e.g. [How to return a PDF from a Web API application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36042614/1220550)

And unless you need hundreds of parameters, specifying the parameters in the URL as you did is the recommended approach.

I wouldn't know why you would consider a "hello world website" (or even *what you mean by that...*) if you already have a full-blown MVC Web App.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Our web-dev who has just taken over the app says it is currently a web service (SOAP) and we're considering changing to a REST API so we don't need to construct a SOAP message (because three different systems a) a web app b) Excel VBA and c) MSSQL need to be able to run it. It would be much easier in SQL to construct a URL (and the same for Excel VBA)

Comment: Just to add a little bit more detail: The web front end and Excel must return the PDF to the user. MSSQL just needs to have it dropped into a folder on the server where it can be accessed.