# WebApi returns blank PDF file

Tags: asp.net, pdf, asp.net-web-api, migradoc, httpresponsemessage

I am using MigraDoc to generate PDF, it saves perfectly on the local machine, but when I send this file stream to webapi, browser opens it with blank content.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                   Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(pdfByteArray))
               };
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
              new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
              {
                   FileName = "MyPdf.pdf"
              };
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
              new MediaTypeHeaderValue(@"application/pdf")
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = pdfByteArray.Length;
return response;
```

When I open developer tools in Chrome I see that some response characters look like this:
[image]

Although when I try to create a local file using the same byte stream:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Create(@"d:\work\Test.pdf"))
{
    new MemoryStream(pdfByteArray).CopyTo(stream);
}
```

It displays correctly the content of the PDF.

I was trying to specify different CharSet in Response Content-Type (like UTF-7, UTF-8, windows-1252 etc) and see that response chars are changed, but the result is same - I see blank PDF. Another note that when I send Json with pdfByteArray encoded in Base64, on UI I am able to decode this and create correct PDF. I am trying to find a way to send application/pdf content and let the browser render PDF correctly.

Comment: `pdfByteArray.Length` vs `letterStreamArray.Length`?

Comment: @Nkosi sorry typo, forgot to change it in SO

Comment: did you try different browsers?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander yes I was trying Chrome, IE and Safari - same result. Maybe there is some IIS configuration you know about?

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov Any time the browser can't display it is because it is getting bad data.

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov can you verify the platform being use. Asp.net Core or Asp.net Web API 2+

Comment: can you try the `Content-Disposition` header `inline` instead of `attachment`?

Comment: @Nkosi Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7. About bad data: can it be that browser can not correctly interpret stream content I am sending?

Comment: Ok then that is the problem, Core is serializing the `HttpResponseMessage` you created. Don't do that.

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov check https://stackoverflow.com/a/36043779/5233410

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov update the post with the entire action method so there is more context about the code.